# Django [AssertionError: 400 != 201]

Tags: python, django, assert, http-status-code-400

I'm a french guy and I'm working on Django. I beggin and I have a error.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.username = 'admin'
    self.password = 'admin'
    self.datetime = 'Tue, 15 Nov 1994 08:12:31 GMT'
    self.temperature = '15.6'
    self.presence = '56'


def test_presence_post(self):
    #frame = 'presence=' + self.presence + '&datetime=2014-12-12 16:45:45'

    c = Client()
    c.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
    response = c.post('/datapresence', {'presence=' + self.presence + '&datetime=2014-12-12 16:45:45'}, 
        content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", HTTP_DATE=datetime)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

My error :
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 400 != 201

If i use Advanced Rest Client, it's OK with a POST request with the url and data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where do you create the admin user you're trying to authenticate in your test database?

Comment: 400 implied bad request. Your data seems to be malformed. Just check the format of the post dictionary sent into the `datapresence` view

Comment: @GarryCairns My setUp is not where I create the user ?

Comment: @karthikr I have this for my datapresence formclass dataPresenceForm(forms.Form):
datetime = forms.DateTimeField() presence = forms.IntegerField()

Comment: Actually, that would be fine. I am asking you to check the `request.POST` dictionary in the view

Comment: Where is that ? I have only that for datapresence
form = dataPresenceForm(request.POST)
if not form.is_valid():
return HttpResponse(status=400, content=form.errors.as_text())
data = form.cleaned_data
instance = BruteMesure.objects.create(
datetime=data['datetime'],
presence=data['presence'],
)
return HttpResponse(status=201, content=instance.id)

Comment: @karthikr is it this ?

Comment: Correct.. do you know how to use pdb ? `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and see the contents of `request.POST.copy()`

Comment: @karthikr I don't know how to see the contents of request.POST.copy()...sorry !

Answer (score 1):

`{'presence=' + self.presence + '&datetime=2014-12-12 16:45:45'}` is a set with a single key and no values, not a dictionary as expected by `post()`. Should be `{'presence': self.presence, 'datetime':'2014-12-12 16:45:45'}`. The server detects an invalid request and returns 400.

I would also try without `content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", HTTP_DATE=datetime`, the default values should be at least as good as the ones provided.

Comment: Without my values, I have this :

IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: IceApp_brutemesure.temperature